# How to get RelatedListHover to work in <apex:detail> with RelatedList="false"

Tags: apex, related-list

I know the question may sound counter-intuitive but I do have a specific use case. Rather then embed a VisualForce page on a Page Layout I have built a VisualForce page that uses the Page Layout and integrates my specific code within it. The following doesn't work and I understand why.

```
<apex:page>
<apex:detail RelatedList="false" RelatedListHover="true" />
<... my specific VisualForce code ...>
<apex:relatedList>
</apex:page>
```

So, I want to display the apex:detail block and then my bit and then the apex:relatedList block. I don't want to display the Related Lists in the detail section because they will be displayed after my specific code. But I do want the RelatedListHover stuff in the detail section. Is it just too much to ask? My question is 'Is there a way to achieve RelatedListHover with apex:detail in this scenario?'

Thanks, Greg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the RelatedListHover part are local links to the related list. You can enter your own `<div> and <a>` tags to replicate Related Lists hovers with proper href. Hope this helps.

Below is sample code:

```
    <div style="visibility: visible;" class="listHoverLinks"><a data-uidsfdc="68" class="linklet" href="#00661000002Z84K_RelatedLineItemList_target" id="00661000002Z84K_RelatedLineItemList_link"><span class="listTitle">Products<span class="count">[0]</span></span></a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. In the absence of a formal way of doing it this code will certainly help.